# File uploading in S3 bucket in Amazon from Android Code

Tags: android, amazon-s3

Hello I am newby to Amazone S3 Bucket functionalities.

Let me explain you my issue. I am trying to add a song from Android Application to Amazone s3 bucket. I want to add public permission to particular song from Android application only. I tried many ways to do so.

like

```
private AmazonS3Client s3;
private TransferUtility transferUtility;

CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context,"us-east-1:fd8bcb7c-b150-4e4d-a1cf-xxxxxxxxxx",Regions.US_EAST_1);

s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest("xxx/audio/usersaudio","test.mp3",fileToUpload).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
PutObjectResult putResponse = s3.putObject(por);

transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, context);
TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("xxx/audio/usersaudio","test.mp3",fileToUpload);

transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
```

Here is my method:-

```
 public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver) {

        transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Log.e("statechange", state + "");
                if (state.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED")) {
                    onPostExecute(state.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                Log.e("Total", "Total Bites " + bytesTotal);
                Log.e("Current", "Current Bites " + bytesCurrent);

                long percentage = (bytesCurrent * 100) / bytesTotal;
                Log.e("percentage", percentage + "%");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
            }

        });
    }
```

It is not giving me any Crash but my device got hang.

Anyone have better solution to give permission while uploading song in s3 bucket.

I want to set permission in coding for now.